# What is the reason for not transferring Bitcoin to the wallet?

Tags: payment

Yesterday I made a payment in the amount of 0.2 bitcoins but it didn't arrive in my wallet account, what should I do?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide some more details. Can you update your question with the wallet you are using, where you were sending the funds from, and the transaction id?

Comment: I collected 0.2 bitcoins on the btc free.cc website and withdrew this money with the Transt wallet, but it still hasn't arrived in my wallet. It says pending payment.
When will it count? Will it really be deposited in my wallet???

Comment: Yes. I collected this amount. For what?

Comment: Those websites are fakes and anyone directing you to them is scamming you. Bitcoin is completely based on personal choice there will basically never be a situation in which you randomly receive bitcoin for free. Especially not these days. If an exchange you are using offers you free coins as a promotion that is different but this is clearly not connected to anything you are seriously familiar with therefore it is clearly a scam.

Comment: Some time ago, I transferred the amount of 0.2 bitcoins that was collected from your site to my wallet, now it is waiting and it has not arrived in my wallet (name of my wallet: trust wallet)
If you please and follow up, I will thank you

Answer (score 1):

> **What is the reason for not transferring Bitcoin to the wallet?**

You should ask the person who is not transferring the money.

One possible reason might be that you are dealing with criminals who are confidence tricksters (conmen) who are running a scam. Perhaps the website is fraudulent or is being used as part of a scam.

> **I collected 0.2 bitcoins on the btc free.cc website ...**

A wise man once wrote "there ain't no such thing as a free lunch" (TANSTAAFL).

> **... and withdrew this money with the Transt wallet,**

Maybe one or more of the following applies

- no one really sent any money.
- it's a fake wallet.
- the wallet isn't fully synchronised yet.